# Как скрыть/показать кнопку?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Как сделать кнопку недоступной, я нашел:

```
btn1.enabled=NO;
```

А как скрыть/показать кнопку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Доброго дня. 
С objective-c я не сталкивался, но почти уверен что это то что вам нужно:

```
btn1.hidden=YES;
btn1.hidden=NO;
```